# rails form data not getting saved to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and trying to make a simple site to start learning. When I submit my form, however, the data isn't saved to the db. I'm really not sure what's wrong, I've been trying to figure it out for a while. If I make a record in the rails console and save it, that one successfully shows up in the db (and on the index page).

calculate.rb:

```
class Calculate < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number, :root
end
```

calculates_controller.rb:

```
class CalculatesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @calculate = Calculate.all
  end

  def new
    @calculate = Calculate.new
  end

  def create
    @calculate = Calculate.new(params[:calculate])
    if @calculate.save
      redirect_to '/calculates'
    else
      render 'new'
      flash[:notice] = "Didn't work"
    end
  end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@calculate) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:number, "Enter the number") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :number %>
  <%= label_tag(:root, "root") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :root %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: and I also have `resources :calculates` in my route.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `form_for`, use the [`form_for` syntax](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

```
<%= form_for(@calculate) do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :number %>
  <%= form.text_field :number %>
  <%= form.label :root %>
  <%= form.text_field :root %>
  <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

this will automatically handle the routes if the `@calculate` is new object it will submit it to create or if it is already saved it will send a put request to `edit action`

Answer (score 0):

Ah hah! I updated my view to:

```
<%= form_for @calculate, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :number %>
    <%= f.text_field :number %>
    <%= f.label :root %>
    <%= f.text_field :root %>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

And now it works. Awesome.