# Following Ruby on Rails Guides: Form posts "nil" values despite logging valid POST data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question is somewhat similar to [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910814/rails-form-data-not-getting-saved-to-db), but in my case, I'm even more of a beginner, and my server is breaking on the first page of the [Ruby-on-Rails getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Basically, the guide walks me through creating a simple blog post app with a comment form. Following the guide, I can create blog posts, and the comment form renders. The comment "show" area even renders, and it displays the correct number of comments, but the values getting stored in the db itself are "nil" for both the "commenter" and "body" fields.

I copied the code straight off the guide, so posting that probably won't add any value. Here is my `development.log` for the interesting event with space added so you can see what I'm seeing:

```
    Started POST "/posts/1/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-17 06:50:32 -0600
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>
"YuuqmOYgsUHoHTYKBDjeE+zkYSAfWbsB4LcUz6btUkU=",

  "comment"=>{"commenter"=>"just me", "body"=>"Yes"},

 "commit"=>"Create Comment", "post_id"=>"1"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id",     "1"]]
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "comments" ("body", "commenter", "created_at",
"post_id",     "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

 [["body", nil], ["commenter", nil],

 ["created_at", Mon, 17 Dec     2012 12:50:32 UTC +00:00], ["post_id", 1],
 ["updated_at", Mon, 17      Dec     2012 12:50:32 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (5.8ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/1
Completed 302 Found in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

## UPDATE

Here's the `comment` model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
 attr_accessible :body, :commenter
 attr_accessor :body, :commenter
end
```

And the `post` controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    begin
       @post = Post.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @post }
        end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        redirect_to posts_path
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.json
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Finally the .erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
 <%= @post.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Content:</b>
  <%= @post.content %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <b>Commenter:</b>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Comment:</b>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

There's gotta be something obvious I'm missing here.

Comment: This seems like a mass-assignment problem. Did you whitelist the attributes you want to be able to mass-assign (that is pass into new, create and update_attributes) in your `Post` model (see 6.4 in the Guide)?

Comment: [This blog post](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/148-protect-mass-assignment) gives great details on the subject. If you set `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` in your `config/application.rb`, Rails will alert you of this specific source of unwanted behavior.

Comment: this VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) looks like string substitution gone wrong. params seem to come in alright, please post you controller code (and maybe the model, since could be a problem with attr_accessible)

Comment: These are great comments.  Yes, I white-listed the two parameters, and I also tried it with whitelist_attributes set to false.  I'll go ahead and post my code, but it's just copied from the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, here it is! (space added)

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
 attr_accessible :body, :commenter

 attr_accessor :body, :commenter

end
```

By adding accessor methods I was bypassing rails' direct access to the data members.  I commented that out and then everything worked.  I guess I thought that had to be there since I had those `MASS-ASSIGN` errors.

Thanks for your valuable comments!