# Rails 4 not storing data, in seeds, or default model saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a simple model called Project. Project has a couple of properties title, description, image_path, date_started, date_ended. When I try to seed my project with this

```
Project.create(
    title: "Project",
    description: "a project",
    image: "http://i.imgur.com/.png",
    date_start: Time.now)
```

it doesn't actually save it to the DB. It does save a record in the DB by assigning an ID but none of the fields are set. I put a validate presence in the model to make sure that it is actually getting some data, but it doesn't throw any errors.

I have also checked in my controller to make sure that it is allowing me to modify the variables

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :image_path, :date_started, :date_ended)
end
```

I am not entirely sure why this isn't saving to the DB and have frankly run out of ideas.

The database I am using is Postgres.

**EDIT-**
Added Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130902003818) do

  create_table "projects", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image"
    t.date     "date_start"
    t.date     "date_end"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Similiar questions that didn't work:

[rails form data not getting saved to db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910814/rails-form-data-not-getting-saved-to-db)

[Ruby on rails - paperclip not saving to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665809/ruby-on-rails-paperclip-not-saving-to-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tweaking the project multiple times. I have come to the conclusion that it must be bugged in some way. I solved this issue by deleting all the "Project" files (Controller, Views, Model) and regenerated them using the scaffold command. It is now working as intended.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

A Status model:

```
class CreateStatuses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :statuses do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And in seeds.rb :

```
Status.create([{ name: "Administrator" }, { name: "Writer" }])
```

When i ran rake db:seed , a row was created but nothing got inserted in the name field.
I think it's related to the new rails 4 feature: [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).
Good exemples are given [here](http://blog.sensible.io/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html).

To make the seed work:

- In Gemfile i added: `gem 'protected_attributes'` then ran `bundle install`
- In the model (status.rb):

  ```
  class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name
  end
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try to bang `create` to reveal the problem as an exception:

```
Project.create!(
    title: "Project",
    description: "a project",
    image: "http://i.imgur.com/.png",
    date_start: Time.now)
```

Then fix it :-)

Comment: Tried adding the ! operator to the create method and it didn't show any exceptions or errors. It also didn't change what it put in the database.

Comment: @Rizowski sorry, no more ideas :(